# How do I use serde to deserialize an optional field from an XML file?

Tags: serialization, rust, serde

I'm trying to deserialize XML file which has element containing nested elements like this:

```xml
<element>
  <nested1/>
  <nested2>
  ..
  <nested2>
</element>
```

But `nested2` is not mandatory and is in some cases not present. When this happens, serde throws an error. Is there a way to mark `nested2` as optional?

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Element {
    nested1: (),
    #[serde ??]
    nested2: (),
}
```